# Docker MySQL container not binding to local port correctly

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect my local 3306 to my docker containers 3306 using docker-compose. This was all working correctly until I encountered an error with MySQL when I tried changing a table name using workbench. Since then I've been unable to connect back to the container with the correct data.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web_old:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./html/Dockerfile
    container_name: mackglobal_old
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      # - ./config/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/000-default.conf
    ports:
      - 8000:80
  db:
    container_name: mysql8_old
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "admin" # same as production so when we create views it doesnt cause definer errors
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    # command: mysqld --innodb_force_recovery=6 # USE THIS LINE IF THE MYSQL CONTAINER CRASHES TO RECOVER DATA IN READ
```

When connecting to the database in my application I am met with this PHP PDO error:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

When I connect to the mysql instance inside the docker container I am able to access the server using the username and password in the docker-compose file and all of my databases and tables are inside the instance. But when connecting to the instance inside workbench every query I make is met with:

```
Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.
```

and when running `SHOW databases;` I only get `information_schema`

Here are the details I've been using to connect to the instance:

Hostname: **MacBook-Pro-2.local (also tried: localhost, 127.0.0.1)**

Port: **3306 (I've also changed the port to 3307 in the compose file and get the same errors)**

Username: **admin**

Password: **root**

Here is my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
default_time_zone='+00:00'
sql_mode=""
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;'
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
lower_case_table_names=2
```

and here is the log when running `docker-compose up --build`:

```
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16 20:15:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16 20:15:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16 20:15:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16T20:15:39.468943Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 1
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16T20:15:39.506466Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16T20:15:40.895843Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16T20:15:41.681805Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16T20:15:41.848877Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16T20:15:41.849540Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16T20:15:41.867833Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql8_old | 2021-02-16T20:15:42.028150Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I should also note that the last environment I used was mysql:8.0.21 but I arrived at the same errors

Any help is greatly appreciated

Addition:

I've also tried restarting docker service and my laptop as well

When running network utility on port 3306 while containers are active:

[Port scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnROZ.png)

EDIT:

Turns out my folder which holds the mysql data `./mysql` in my docker compose file is now corrupt (without error) and I'm still unable to access anything in recovery mode. Luckily I had a backup but I lost all my recent changes that I made. I still am unsure what went wrong so I'm leaving this unsolved

Comment: Seems like the error says pretty clearly that your database does not exist (or you don't have access to see it). What is your question?

Comment: @ArSeN When inside my docker container I have access to three schemas I created: mgedb, mgddb, and userdata. These are not present in workbench and I'm unable to determine why the instance isn't mirroring to localhost properly

Answer (score 1):

In my docker-compose.yml, I made my mysql container like this:

```
mysql8-service:
        image: mysql:8
        container_name: mysql8-container
        ports:
            - "4306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        restart: always # always restart unless stopped manually
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
        networks:
            - nginx-php74-mysql8-node
```

It make me able to save my database in the folder of my app, and my credentials are good.